Models and measurement techniques for work-related cognitive and physiological fatigue
I would like to know more about attempts at comprehensive models of work-related fatigue, or identifying strongly determining, measurable, correlating factors.
This includes both cognitive and physiological aspects.
The goal is to understand if it’s possible to prospectively avoid fatigue by measuring and predicting its levels.
Some starting ideas:

Theoretical models of cognitive and physiological fatigue related to sustained mental effort in work environments. Has anyone compared athletic training programs using heart rate monitoring to some way of measuring “work-related mental exertion”? Mental doesn’t have to mean to mental math, but just the act of going to work which requires a lot of self-regulation.

Physiological markers of fatigue:

Heart Rate Variability (HRV)
Electrodermal Activity (EDA) / Skin Conductance
Pupil dilation as an indicator of cognitive load
Cortisol levels
Other relevant hormones (e.g., adrenaline, norepinephrine)
Blood glucose levels
Hemoglobin levels?


Current technologies for measuring these markers in real-world settings:

Wearable devices (e.g., Polar H10, Garmin HRM-Pro Plus, Oura Ring)
Continuous Glucose Monitors (CGMs)
At-home blood testing kits
Saliva testing for cortisol
Eye-tracking devices for pupillometry


Validation studies on the reliability and practicality of these measurement techniques for daily use.

Research on how these various markers correlate with subjective experiences of fatigue (and perhaps objective measures of cognitive performance).

Any studies on using combinations of these markers to create predictive models of fatigue onset.

Practical considerations for long-term self-monitoring of these physiological markers.

Ongoing research or future directions regarding continuous, non-invasive monitoring techniques.


I'm aware of concepts like ego depletion and research on the prefrontal cortex's role in self-regulation, but it doesn’t sound very applicable at first glance.
Some research I've found includes:

Cognitive fatigue models:

Boksem and Tops (2008) proposed a model linking cognitive fatigue to cost/reward evaluations in the brain [1].
Hockey's (2013) motivational control theory of cognitive fatigue [2].


Physiological markers:

Marcora et al. (2009) studied the effect of mental fatigue on physical performance, linking cognitive and physical fatigue [3].
Gergelyfi et al. (2015) investigated pupil dilation as a marker of cognitive fatigue [4].


HRV and fatigue:

Segerstrom and Nes (2007) linked HRV to self-regulatory effort and fatigue [5].


Cortisol and cognitive performance:

Lupien et al. (2007) reviewed cortisol's effects on human cognition [6].


Integrative approaches:

Danhof-Pont et al. (2011) reviewed biomarkers in chronic fatigue syndrome, touching on multiple systems [7].



However, these studies don't fully address practical, non-invasive measurement techniques suitable for long-term use, with personalized thresholds for intervention to prevent fatigue.
Perhaps these may help:

Any recent (post-2020) comprehensive reviews or meta-analyses on cognitive and physiological fatigue in knowledge work.
Studies attempting to create predictive models of fatigue onset using multiple biomarkers.
Research on the efficacy of continuous monitoring technologies (e.g., wearables, CGMs) in fatigue management.
Any emerging technologies or methodologies for non-invasive, continuous monitoring of relevant biomarkers (e.g., cortisol, brain activity).


Some research found so far:

Boksem, M. A., & Tops, M. (2008). Mental fatigue: costs and benefits. Brain research reviews, 59(1), 125-139.

Hockey, G. R. J. (2013). The psychology of fatigue: Work, effort and control. Cambridge University Press.

Marcora, S. M., Staiano, W., & Manning, V. (2009). Mental fatigue impairs physical performance in humans. Journal of applied physiology, 106(3), 857-864.

Gergelyfi, M., Jacob, B., Olivier, E., & Zénon, A. (2015). Dissociation between mental fatigue and motivational state during prolonged mental activity. Frontiers in behavioral neuroscience, 9, 176.

Segerstrom, S. C., & Nes, L. S. (2007). Heart rate variability reflects self-regulatory strength, effort, and fatigue. Psychological science, 18(3), 275-281.

Lupien, S. J., Maheu, F., Tu, M., Fiocco, A., & Schramek, T. E. (2007). The effects of stress and stress hormones on human cognition: Implications for the field of brain and cognition. Brain and cognition, 65(3), 209-237.

Danhof-Pont, M. B., van Veen, T., & Zitman, F. G. (2011). Biomarkers in burnout: a systematic review. Journal of psychosomatic research, 70(6), 505-524.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232606033_A_motivational_control_theory_of_cognitive_fatigue

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6139359/

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0278262622000380


Perhaps I should start by following the academic practices of an actual literature review?

Hello Julius, questions on the Stack Exchange network are expected to focus on a single answerable question. They are not intended for broad discussions of a topic or interest. As written, you question is essentially one or more PhD theses. I doubt it is possible, but you could try editing your question into a single, brief, answerable question.

I see that you edited your question but you didn't address the problem @IanCampbell raised. Quite frankly, I can't even find a question you're asking. The entire text of your "question" contains only one question mark, and that's just a parenthetical comment.
